# Create and Remove Components Dynamically in Angular 13+

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to delete child component, parent will delete the last child only and after that, it shows that index is -1 from hostView and can't delete the child from view

this is my Child View

```
<button (click)="remove_me()" >I am a Child {{unique_key}}, click to Remove
</button>
```

this is my Child Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ParentComponent } from '../parent/parent.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
})
export class ChildComponent {
  public unique_key: number;
  public parentRef: ParentComponent;

  constructor() {}

  remove_me() {
    console.log(this.unique_key);
    this.parentRef.remove(this.unique_key);
  }
}
```

this is my Parent View

```
<button type="button" (click)="AddChild()">
I am Parent, Click to create Child
</button>
<div>
<ng-template #viewContainerRef></ng-template>
</div>
```

this is my Parent Component

```
import {
  ComponentRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ViewChild,
  Component,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild('viewContainerRef', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  vcr!: ViewContainerRef;
  ref!: ComponentRef<ChildComponent>;

  child_unique_key: number = 0;
  componentsReferences = Array<ComponentRef<ChildComponent>>();

  constructor() {}

  AddChild() {
    this.ref = this.vcr.createComponent(ChildComponent);
    let childComponent = this.ref.instance;
    childComponent.unique_key = ++this.child_unique_key;
    childComponent.parentRef = this;
  }

  remove(key: number) {
    const index = this.vcr.indexOf(this.ref.hostView);
    console.log(index);
    if (index != -1) {
      this.vcr.remove(index);
    }
    // removing component from the list
    this.componentsReferences = this.componentsReferences.filter(
      (x) => x.instance.unique_key !== key
    );
  }
}
```

I tried the methods from older Angular versions that supports ComponentFactoryResolver, but I want to upgrade the version of Angular

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious errors in your code:

- You initialize a property
  `componentsReferences = Array<ComponentRef<ChildComponent>>();`
  but never populate it.
- even if you filter out that element from that list you dont remove it from the view-container. Which is why angular wont remove the component. (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

But I have to say that there are quite some more issues with your code.
You should never ever have a ref from your child-component to your parent component for example.

I suggest you have a look at  and follow through with the angular tour of heros because dynamic component creation is quite a complex topic and it seems that you should stick to some basics first.

For example could your desired outcome be done kinda like this:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  uniqueKeys: number [] = [];
  private counter = 0; 

  addKey() {
    this.uniqueKeys.push(this.counter);
    this.counter++;
  }

  removeLastKey() {
    this.uniqueKeys.pop();
  }
}
```

in parent-component.html:

```
  <app-child *ngFor="let key of uniqueKeys" [key]=key></app-child>
```

and in child-component.html you can have your @Input() for the key property if needed...
Just check https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: your using classic method, my code removes child components, but the problem is with the `this.vcr.indexOf(this.ref.hostView);` and `this.vcr.remove(index);` returns -1 at 2nd click

Comment: my syntax was ok, only a little edits made and it's worked!